# How to Hidden List Instance in Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: 2007, list, wss-3.0

Is this possible to list instance hidden using attribute because I read this post [from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476062%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
and there are no available hidden attribute. So how can I hide a list instance in my web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `SPList.Hidden=true` for that list either programmatically or using Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

It can also be hidden via SharePoint Designer (right click list, properties, tick hidden from browser click OK).